# After upgrading, Magento 2.4.2 shows blank checkout form

Tags: php, magento2, magento2.4

I upgraded my website from Magento 2.3.3 to Magento 2.4.2. Everything worked fine but on the frontend after the buy now button checkout page is blank.

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide more information like Magento, PHP version, console errors (if any).

Comment: magento 2.4.2 & php 7.4. JS is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checkout Page was blank because the Openpay payment method was creating trouble.
I debugged the same using log files.

Merchant ID was missing.